# BigQuery Transfer vs BigQuery load

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to schedule loading data to BigQuery tables from GCS-buckets to BigQuery. What's the core difference if I use bigquery-transfer vs scheduling timely bigquery-loads ?

Answer (score 5):

They are the same. BQ Transfer still creates a BQ load job for you.